# How to print multiple values, keys dicts python in one loop "?

Tags: python

I'm trying to print two values, keys from two  different dictionaries  in one loop, to do some  adding*, but I could not able to do it correctly together in one loop, my code

```
def code (file):
    dict1  = {}
    dict2  = {}

    f = open('text.txt', 'r')

    for line in f.readlines():
        line =line.strip()
        parts = line.split(" ")            
    try:
        (w1, w2) = [parts[0], parts[1]]
        word2 = (wr1+' '+wr2)                                           
    # dict2words  
           if word2 in dict2:
                dict2[word2] +=1
            else:
                dict2 [word2] = 1
     #dict1word       
          if w[1] in dict1:
                dict1[w[1]] +=1
          else:
                dict1[w[1]] = 1                
    expect: 
         print ('no word')
code(file)
```

My file look like this

```
car1  BMW
car2  Benz 
Car3  Kia 
car1  BMW
car4  BMW
```

with this code its count two word happen together (bigram) and unigram(2th  word) in different dict like this

```
dic2       dic1     
Car1 BMW  2  BMW  3 
Car2 Benz 1  Benz 1 
Car3 kia  1  kia  2 
Car4 BMW  1  BMW  3
```

(the bigram car1 bmw happen two time and Bmw unigram happen 3 time in the whole carpus)

I manged to print them correctly separately, but could not print it together to do some calculation like this (the code run correctly but together give the wrong output)

```
for k, v in sorted(dict1.iteritems()):
       print k, v
for k1, v1 in sorted(dict2.iteritems()):
       print k1,v1
```

My question here how to print two keys and values at same time in same loop/sorted order to get this result

```
 dic2     dic1       result 
Car1 BMW  2  BMW 3    2 * 3  
Car2 Benz 1  Benz 1   1 * 1 
Car3 kia  1  kia  2   1 * 2 
Car4 BMW  1  BMW  3   1 * 3
```

Comment: Will the two dictionaries always have exactly the same keys?

Comment: `for word2  in dict2:  if not word2 in dict2 :` - this code makes no sense...

Comment: Thank for your fast reply,  different keys and value because I'm taking the second word alone and count it in the whole corpus like in the example above. I  fixed the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no "simple" way to do this.

You need to apply the same logic as you apply while you're dividing bigrams.
You need to iterate over dict2, for every key you'll see, split it, get unigram, get count from dict1. I.e.:

```
for bigram, bigram_count in dict2.items():
    unigram = bigram.split(' ')[-1]
    unigram_count = dict1[unigram]
    print(bigram, bigram_count, unigram, unigram_count, bigram_count * unigram_count)
```

Offtopic: you can simplify your code with [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict). Initialize `dict1` and `dict2` as `defaultdict(int)` and you can skip `if w in dict: ... else: ...` routine

Answer (score 1):

As Slam mentioned using defauldict, it can be done in the following way.

```
from collections import defaultdict
def code (file):
    dictionary1 = defaultdict(list)
    dictionary2 = defaultdict(int)
    f = open('text.txt', 'r')
    partsarray = []
    for line in f.readlines():
        line =line.strip()
        parts = line.split(" ")
        parts.remove('')
        partsarray.append(parts)            
    try:
        i=0
        for part,partforadding in partsarray:
            if(part in dictionary1):
                i+=1
                dictionary1[part].remove(i)
                dictionary1[part].append(i+1)
            else:
                dictionary1[part].append(partforadding)
                dictionary1[part].append(1)
            dictionary2[partforadding]+=1
        print(dictionary1)
        print(dictionary2)          
    except Exception as error:
        print("The error is") 
        print(error)
        print ('no word')
code("text.txt")
```

The output is

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'car1': ['BMW', 2], 'car2': ['Benz', 1], 'Car3': ['Kia', 1], 'Car2': ['Kia', 1], 'car4': ['BMW', 1]})
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'BMW': 3, 'Benz': 1, 'Kia': 2})
```

In the file that you mentioned , car2 has both Benz and Kia. But in the output Car2 has only Benz. Is the data correct? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, you are correct was an error in the data, and  I fixed it now, I thought defauldict approach will make the code simpler, but its seem not, but thanks for explaining it in detail.